# pspicture environment overlays text in figure float

Tags: pstricks, pst-tree

I have a strange problem witih PSTricks, `pst-tree` and the `pspicture` environment. I use a `figure` float and a simple tree. When I put a `pspicture` environment around it, the picture is placed above the text. What am I doing wrong?

Note: when I remove the `pspicture` environment, everything is working fine. But without the `pspicture` environment, I can't use things like the `psbrace`.

[image: Wrong output]

```
\documentclass[english]{article}


\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}


\begin{document}
    Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem
    ipsum. 

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{pspicture}(3,3)
        \pstree{\Tcircle{ }}
          {
            \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
            \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
          }
        \end{pspicture}

        \caption{}
    \end{figure}

    Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because the contents of your `pspicture` are extending outside of its bounds.

If you add the line `\psgrid` immediately after your `\begin{pspicture}`, you'll see that you get

[image: screenshot]

There are many ways to fix this- the easiest is perhaps to change the viewing window of your `pspicture`, to something like

```
\begin{pspicture}(5,-5)
```

[image: screenshot]

The general syntax is

```
\begin{pspicture}(xmin,ymin)(xmax,ymax)
```

In addition to this, you'll probably want to add `\centering` to your environment. The complete code follows for your reference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-tree}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem
ipsum. 

\begin{figure}
   \centering
   \begin{pspicture}(5,-5)
   \psgrid
   \pstree{\Tcircle{ }}
         {
           \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
           \pstree{\Tr{ }}{\Tfan}
         }
   \end{pspicture}
   \caption{}
\end{figure}

Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum. 

\end{document}
```

Once you're done with construction, simply comment out the `\psgrid` line, and you'll be finished.

Comment: @Werner Thanks, that's high praise indeed from a guru :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I had the idea to enable the grid to see what's going on, but I didn't think of setting negative values. But this means, I have to know size of the tree in advance?

Comment: @lumbric During construction, I think the answer is typically, yes. You can use `pspicture*` which will automatically clip the picture, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: No, clipping doesn't help me either. I'm just wonderung why it's working without `pspicture` and why I should use the `pspicture` environment then (well some things are not possible without). Questions and thoughts from a PStricks newbie... :)

Comment: @lumbric I tend to think of the `pspicture` environment as the 'bounding box' for the picture. Without the environment, `PSTricks` will do its best to figure out the 'bounding box' on its own- as you've described, sometimes it will work, but you may not be able to use all commands.